# How may I add children's fields to parent with eloquent without JOIN?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table which is a parent and child at the same time. Then I want to add child's field to parent entity.

```
Types::query()
        ->select()
        ->with(['typeChild' => function($query) {
            return $query->select('id','rank as child_rank');
        }])
      ->get()
```

I tried to do `withCount` and this function returns result of counting and adds this field to parent, but I need another result.
Also I don't want to add JOIN, even through SCOPE. Therefore, does it have a method to do it?
And it has to look like that [image]

Comment: You're already using a `JOIN`. If you use `with`, Laravel will build the query with an `inner join`. Also, how did you define the relationship between Types and typeChild?

Comment: @stef $this->hasOne(self::class,'parent_id','id')